# Running jekyll as a child process in Gulp/Node

Tags: node.js, jekyll, gulp

I'm trying to build a jekyll site using Gulp.js. I've read that I shouldn't use a plugin in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293999/use-jekyll-with-gulp).

I've been investigating using a child process as suggested but I keep getting an error:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
```

Here's my gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('jekyll', function (){
    spawn('jekyll', ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
});

gulp.task('default', ['jekyll']);
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm on Node 0.10.25, Win 7.

**EDIT**
I've had a google around ENOENT errors previously. Have checked my path and Ruby is there and I can run jekyll from the command line. Still no joy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I also had this problem and found the answer to using spawn.

The problem is with how Node finds executables on Windows. For more details look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17537559

In short, change `spawn('jekyll', ['build'])` to `spawn('jekyll.bat', ['build'])` in order to get spawn to work.

Comment: SpikeMeister, I just saw your answer by googling for my own problem. Sorry didn't accept and vote it up earlier. 
Do you know if the .bat fix works on Mac/Unix machines?
Made my day!

Comment: Re my previous comment. You can set the command based on the OS:

`var jekyll = process.platform === "win32" ? "jekyll.bat" : "jekyll";`

then just run:

`spawn(jekyll' ['build'])`

Answer (score 9):

So I ended up using `exec` instead. Here's my gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('jekyll', function (){
exec('jekyll build', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
});
});
```

[Here's a post about the differences](http://www.hacksparrow.com/difference-between-spawn-and-exec-of-node-js-child_process.html)

Answer (score 1):

A few years later, you can now use [`cross-spawn`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-spawn), which takes care of cross-platform issues with node's `spawn`. It's a straight replacement for Node's `spawn`.

Install to your project with

```
npm install cross-spawn
```

Then add

```
const spawn = require('cross-spawn');
```

to your script.

Then in your gulp script use as normal:

```
gulp.task('jekyll', function (){
    spawn('jekyll', ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
});
```

If you're using this in a non-gulp script:

```
var jekyll = spawn('bundle exec jekyll build');
```