# Using Jekyll with Gulp and Livereload

Tags: jekyll, livereload, gulp

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293999/use-jekyll-with-gulp/21403905#21403905) has hinted me on how to run Jekyll with Gulp.

It works fine except I’m unable to trigger livereload (but it runs without errors).

My knowledge of Node is limited, so I’m probably missing something...

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var refresh = require('gulp-livereload');
var lr = require('tiny-lr');
var server = lr();

gulp.task('jw', function(){
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
        j     = spawn('jekyll', ['-w', 'build']);

    j.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data); // works fine
        refresh(server); // doesn’t trigger
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gulp-livereload` requires files piped into it via `gulp.src()` or other [vinyl](https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl) input sources.  In this case, I recommend [adding `gulp-watch`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-watch) to watch for the files that Jekyll writes, and reload based on that.

It would look something like this:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var refresh = require('gulp-livereload');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var lr = require('tiny-lr');
var server = lr();

gulp.task('jw', function(){
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
        j     = spawn('jekyll', ['-w', 'build']);

    j.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data); // works fine
    });

    watch({glob: '/glob/path/to/jekyll/output'}, function(files) {
        // update files in batch mode
        return files.pipe(refresh(server));
    });
});
```

As long as Jekyll only rewrites changed files, this will work *perfectly*.  However, if it overwrites everything, then livereload will do little more than refresh the browser on every change.

Comment: It works but Jekyll replace all files, so livereload is triggered for each. Is there a way to trigger it only once?

Comment: I updated the answer to use `gulp-watch` in batch mode.  I also had a mistake in the way I configured `watch`, I apologize for that.  It needed the input files specified as `{glob:<<inputfiles>>}`.

Comment: @OverZealous this isn't working for me, I added a `console.log` in the `watch` callback and it's not called when the site is changing. My path is `_site`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger livereload at the end of the build, making it reload the page so you won't have multiple refresh :